# Installing ubuntu on a formatted NTFS drive

Tags: installation, boot, ntfs

I am supposed to fix a laptop in which the hard disk was recently formatted. It contained Windows 7 before. 
I am trying a fresh install of ubuntu 12.04 from a bootable USB, but haven't been able to go past the maintenance shell. 
In the maintenance shell, I tried out the following:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sda
Failed to determine whether /dev/sda is mounted: No such file or directory
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing/
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk
```

The trouble may be that there aren't permissions to write on the ntfs partition. The partition might not be corrupt. When I check the filesystem, I get this:

```
root@ubuntu:~# fsck /dev/sda
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
ext2fs_check_if_mount: Can't check if mounted due to missing mtab file while determining whether /dev/sda is mounted. Bad magic number in super-block 
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2 filesystem.
```

So, it must be an ntfs file system. that's why I tried ntfsfix but that didn't work. 
The hard disk is not partitioned. When I run

```
fdisk -l
```

it shows /dev/sda (~500 GB) and /dev/sdb (boot recovery) .
I have been trying to run

```
badblocks -v /dev/sda
```

But, suddenly the laptop just reboots and I don't even get to the maintenance shell stage.
I select "Install ubuntu" and it gets stuck at the wait screen forever.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try /dev/sdaX --> X is a number from 1 to n.